# некорректное отображение в Android Studio Xubuntu

Tags: linux, android-studio, xubuntu

[image: Некорректное отображение символов]

Такая проблема возникла сразу после установки из репозитория Andriod Studio в Xubuntu 18.04. Перед скачиванием настроек и необходимых компонентов установщик показал, что у меня нет ia32, но установить ia32 я не смог, т.к не найден пакет в репозиториях.
Помогите сделать, чтобы символы отображались корректно.

Comment: Ты через `umake` ставил?

Comment: как вариант, можно запусти с `LC_ALL=C`... если же решать проблему, то смотри, какие шрифты оно использует и установи, чтобы использовался шрифт для которого точно есть кириллица...